# Error code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 arrow

Tags: mysql

I'm having this problem while i try to do queries in mysql. The exercise is this one:

**Write a query to find the first name (first name, last name) and salary of employees with a higher salary than all employees with the same last name as ‘Grant’.**+

The database is a bookinfo.sql one, with a company schema.

And i tried to solve this in the way down below.

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY 
FROM employees 
WHERE SALARY >
(SELECT salary FROM employees WHERE last_name = 'Grant');
```

But the error keeps happening. Does anyone know how to solve it, or another way to do it so this won't occur? Thank you beforehand!

Comment: You have to make sure that only a single result is returned. This can be achieved using `LIMIT 1` like: `WHERE last_name = 'Grant' LIMIT 1`

Comment: "same last name as ‘Grant’" doesn't sound like find last name = 'Grant', sounds more complicated.  maybe the full exercise provides more info; a link would be nice

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you use a subquery in an expression, the subquery must be guaranteed to return no more than 1 column and 1 row. This is sometimes called a "scalar subquery" because the result is exactly one scalar value (or NULL if the subquery matches no rows).

But the way you've written the subquery, you search on a non-unique column `last_name`, so it's very possible that the subquery finds multiple matches. That is not a scalar subquery.

To solve this, you could make sure the subquery returns only a single value. You really need to match only the single greatest salary among employees with last_name='Grant', to be sure your outer query matches rows with greater salaries than that.

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY 
FROM employees 
WHERE SALARY >
(SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees WHERE last_name = 'Grant');
```

Another solutions is to use an OUTER JOIN, trying to match greater salaries for employees named 'Grant', and if there is no match, the outer join will return NULLs in the joined table.

```
SELECT e1.FIRST_NAME, e1.LAST_NAME, e1.SALARY 
FROM employees AS e1
LEFT OUTER JOIN employees AS e2
 ON e1.salary < e2.salary AND e2.last_name = 'Grant'
WHERE e2.salary IS NULL AND e1.last_name <> 'Grant';
```

Comment: sadly, it doesn't check "*guaranteed* to return no more than 1", just that it did not for the data entered.

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem, didn't know how to use the syntax of the left outer join in there:)! Now i do.